Stuck on lock screen and no password will work on Ubuntu Studio 24.04 live USB
Stuck on lock screen and no password will work on Ubuntu Studio 24.04 live USB.
I do not want to restart because I am running a long ddrescue operation (2TB) in a graphical terminal. I tried Ctrl+Alt+F1 (and others) to switch to a different tty in text mode but just get a flashing cursor and occasional system message (only unrelated "[ 4081.989537] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination"). I can instantly switch back to the lock screen at any time using Ctrl+Alt+F2 (no lag there). Researching the topic shows that people suggest trying "ubuntu" or "ubuntu-studio" for the password (I also tried ubuntustudio at random) but those passwords do not work, nor will leaving it blank (though leaving it blank worked for the "sudo ddrescue" operation I started before the screen locked). Is it possible that ddrescue is interrupting the tty switching and that the system will eventually let me log in on a different tty? Or, is there actually a lock screen password that will work?
:edit: 1. If I press Ctrl+Alt and various F keys enough times, I can see that it says "Authentication failure" for about 1/60th of a second (varies each time). 2. In the graphical session (Ctrl+Alt+F2) I tried pressing the switch user symbol on the lock screen prompt then was able to get back in as ubuntu-studio but just get a black background and mouse cursor (which I can only move--No mouse buttons nor Alt+F2 do anything). Therefore should the live CD authentication configuration be reported as a bug since there is no way to get back in, even from another TTY?

Known bug, please see the release notes before asking these questions in the future. Thanks.
